# HTML popover in QML

Tags: qt, qml, popover

I need to create a popover (like web version) in QML. I've tried several different approaches, but am not satisfied that it fits the 'real' popover look.

[image: It should look like this]

Has anyone done this or have and suggestions as to how to approach it? I am currently stuck at using a separate image for the pointer, but that has many issues that come with it

Comment: Your question is too vague. You say you've tried "several different approaches", but you don't tell us what those approaches are. And you don't tell us what you didn't like about them. Please start by taking our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to ask good questions that will get you good answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in multiple ways. For example, you can customize a ToolTip, or build your own custom popover control from scratch in QML, which looks like this:

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15

Rectangle {
    id: main
    anchors.fill: parent

    color: "#999999"

    Button {
        id: btn
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "click me"

        property bool popVisible: false
        onClicked: popVisible = !popVisible
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: pop
        parent: btn

        property int padding: 10

        x: parent.width + 12
        width: col.width + padding*2
        height: col.height + padding*2
        visible: btn.popVisible

        radius: 3

        Rectangle {
            rotation: 45
            width: 12
            height: 12
            x: -width/2
            y: height
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            id: col
            spacing: 10
            x: pop.padding
            y: pop.padding
            Repeater {
                model: 6
                Text {
                    text: "Item in popover #" + index
                }
            }
        }

        DropShadow {
            parent: btn
            anchors.fill: pop
            visible: pop.visible
            source: pop
            radius: 8
            samples: 16
            color: "#60000000"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use QML Loader Element to display your popover. If you want to draw any shape simply use Shape QML Type. To make popover more fancy use DropShadow QML Type. Search for documentation of those elements, there are several examples how to use them. This should solve issue.